# What's the meaning of url path in form_for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

A `copy` action and `copy.html.erb` are defined in our rails 3.2 app. This copy action is to copy from the current record, allowing user modify slightly and submit for creation just like `new`. Here is the header of the `copy.html.erb`:

```
<%= form_for @engine_config, :as => :engine_config, :url => engine_configs_path do |f| %>
```

After clicking `save`, it hits `create` in controller and this is what we wanted.

Our question here is what the engine_configs_path stands for? Usually `engine_configs_path` is for index. Here the form is for create and is not index. What's the reasoning of this index path on create form?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you do `bundle exec rake routes` you will see something similar to this;

```
engine_configs GET        /engine_configs(.:format)                               engine_configs#index
               POST       /engine_configs(.:format)                               engine_configs#create
```

Which means `engine_configs_path` works with both `GET` for `index` controller action and `POST` for `create` controller action.

Therefore `engine_configs_path` refers to the url the form is posted to in the controller.

Answer (score 4):

**Form**

You generally don't need to define the `url` argument in your `form` - Rails' [`form_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html) helper takes an initialized class object & extracts the required data for it automatically:

From the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html):

> Typically, a form designed to create or update a resource reflects the
>   identity of the resource in several ways:
>
> - (i) the url that the form is
>     sent to (the form element's action attribute) should result in a
>     request being routed to the appropriate controller action (with the
>     appropriate :id parameter in the case of an existing resource)
> - (ii)
>     input fields should be named in such a way that in the controller
>     their values appear in the appropriate places within the params hash,
> - (iii) for an existing record, when the form is initially
>     displayed, input fields corresponding to attributes of the resource
>     should show the current values of those attributes.
>
> In Rails, this is usually achieved by creating the form using form_for
>   and a number of related helper methods. form_for generates an
>   appropriate form tag and yields a form builder object that knows the
>   model the form is about. Input fields are created by calling methods
>   defined on the form builder, which means they are able to generate the
>   appropriate names and default values corresponding to the model
>   attributes, as well as convenient IDs, etc. Conventions in the
>   generated field names allow controllers to receive form data nicely
>   structured in params with no effort on your side.

--

**Route**

Your specific question is regarding the `route` your `form_for` method will use

As per [w3c standards](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13), HTML forms are defaulted to `POST` data. This means whenever you use a `form_for` helper in Rails, it will automatically use the `POST` variant of your routes

As described by `Acacia`, if you're using [`resourceful`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resources-on-the-web) routes, you'll get a series of routes like this:

[image]

This means you can call the same route (`engine_configs_path`) with the HTTP Verb of `POST` to send to a specific `controller#action`, which is what's happening for you

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour of `engine_configs_path` depends on the HTTP verb. That is, an HTTP GET to `engine_configs_path` will show the index; an HTTP POST to `engine_configs_path` will create a new one. `form_for` can check whether `@engine_config` exists in the DB or not via `@engine_config.new_record?`, so it knows to do a POST instead of a PUT.